# %s in joomla .ini file

Tags: joomla

anyone know the meaning of %s in joomla ? I found it in .ini file but don't know how they had been fecth or converted.

I found the example of the flowing code in `.INI`

```
EMAIL_MSG=This is an e-mail from (%s) sent by %s (%s). You may also find the following link interesting: %s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used for string substitution using sprintf

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php